# Window - Lock Program Background

Tags: c++, windows, service

I want to lock a program in background by adding a **service** to background. The user needs to input password to use the program.

```
sc create newservice binpath = "C:\Users\User\Test.exe"
```

The problem is, I am not sure that How can I write the program.
First, what programming language can I use? Cmd, C++ or others?
Second, how can I write this exe?

I have heard this from my friend, but I am not sure how to write this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I dont understand your question. What lock? What is purpose of this?

Comment: I mean that once the browser is opened, the lock will force ask for password and if the password is wrong, it will force kill the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note, background process not must be service.

Second note, if you wish wrote service, take in account Vista and above session isolation. Also service may run in another account.

Third note. How do you 'trap' browser? Code injection? Finding by process name/ window name?  .... Many counterattacks exists, so this is not trivial thing.

Forth note, What if stop service or close/kill your process?

Fifth note, how do you wish store passwords? If as plain text, every skilled person obstruct your app. If encrypted, more code you must wrote...

Sixth note, nobody on SO.com wrote code for wish without you.

Comment: Well, MY FRIEND told me that he can make a background service as executable file so the service will loop and once the imagename exists and is running, there will be a window popping up and ask for password. Stopping the service is **okay**, as people may not easily find the service. Also, I would just want to save my password IN the executable file.

Comment: Again, YOU DONT NEED SERVICE TO RUN EXECUTABLE IN THE LOOP.

Comment: Okey I rename Firefox.exe to the IDONTNEEDPASSWORD.exe and your app is useless.

Comment: Alright, but I just want people without GOOD PROGRAMMING KNOWLEDGE to be unable to use a program. A good programmer can do a lot of things, which a non-experienced programmer cannot.